# how to resolve Column Transformer object has no attribute '_features_names_in" while running a notebook for sample scoring in IBM Watson studio

Tags: python

I tried to change the version of my notebook from python 3.8 to 3.9 and tried to run
the project in watson studio.

It gave me the below error while running the notebook for sample scoring  in IBM Watson studio

Column Transformer object has no attribute '_features_names_in"
As a fix i tried to change the version of  software specification to "runtime-22.1-py.3.9"
and changed the scikit version from 0.23 to  scikit-learn_1.0 version.

Now the problem is model is created, but deployment status shows "In progress" even after completing 30 minutes.
After 30 minutes it gives error " Deployment Failed -some pods missing -contact IBM Support"